# JS Bundle: How can I ensure that another developer building the frontend bundle will have the same dependencies?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, bundle

I currently use Vue at my startup and right now, we don't have a CI system so each week, everything we're releasing gets merged to a release branch andI manually build the assets from there.  The result bundle gets merged into master and becomes a part of production.  I'll be away for a weeks and I want to ensure that if another developer has to make a frontend change, they build the assets properly.  Some of them use a different operating system so is there a way I can ensure it will build the bundle as expected from my package.json?

Comment: If you have a `package.lock.json` they'll be using the same exact dependencies as you are using.

Comment: Make sure you check your lock file into version control and you should be good to go. (Both npm and yarn generate lock files)

Comment: awesome, thanks Nick and Minusfour!